# create java classes based on values defined in .properties file

Tags: java, class, properties

I wonder if somebody has already met with a requirement to make a processing in **Java** depending on values defined in a .properties file  and what would be the best approach to achieve that ? For example, a property file will have some key/value pairs like that:

```
file.input=csv
data.type=multi
data.separator=;
...etc
```

So in this case, depending on a property value(for example, 'csv'), I'll call CSV processing related classes, depending on 'data.type' value, I'll update the corresponding model values (e.g. class MultiCastXXX). The aim is to have something more or less generic like an API and be able to process no matter what is defined in a property file (of course with some conventions and restrictions applied). What do you think, any ideas ? Thank you.

Comment: This can be done using Abstract Factory pattern.

Comment: Look at [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) or [Apache commons configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/)

Comment: I know the AbstractFactory pattern, so no way to skip the check with if-else (or switch-case) statement ? I mean, if (properties.get("data.type")).equals('multi') => create this stuff, else if ..., etc ?