# Create method name based on values in configuration file in Java

Tags: java, lombok

I have this in my config.properties file.

```
DBServerName=SomeServer
DBUserId=myId
```

I know how to create a Configuration java class so that this works

```
Configuration.get("DBServerName");
```

However, I am trying to create a Configuration file where I can make the following call.

```
Configuration.getDBServerName() ;
```

I do not actually want to write the getDBServerName() method. I want to Configuration class to read the properties file and create the corresponding getXXX() methods automagically.

Please help.

Before anyone points out, I have read the following, and I am looking for answers beyond what have been mentioned here.

1. [create java classes based on values defined in .properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28217027/create-java-classes-based-on-values-defined-in-properties-file)

***Update 1*** 
The lombok folks seem to have solved this. Trying out http://notatube.blogspot.in/2010/12/project-lombok-creating-custom.html

Comment: But reflection is...

Answer (score -1):

I think you should read properties file as text file and push data into array
Example

```
public class ReadPropertiesFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("test.properties");
            FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file);
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.load(fileInput);
            fileInput.close();

            Enumeration enuKeys = properties.keys();
            while (enuKeys.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String) enuKeys.nextElement();
                String value = properties.getProperty(key);
                System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But no, this is not what I had asked about.